# How to reopen stdout if it is closed by the process who called exec

Tags: c, linux, process, exec

Is it possible to reopen stdout, if it is already closed.

For example the below code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    fcntl(1,F_SETFD,FD_CLOEXEC) ; 
    execve("./test2",NULL, NULL);   
    printf("Can you see me [TWO]\n");
}
```

The above code closes Standard output file descriptor and then calls execve. The code for test2 is below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
    printf(" standard output\n");
    perror("standard error");
}
```

Output:
standard error: Bad file descriptor

Is there any way of opening stdout in test2.c

Comment: I'm guessing your use case is a little more complex then the mcve... Make a copy of `stdout` using `dup` before the exec. After the exec and close, use `dup2` on your copy to make fd 1 point to `stdout` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is important to notice - you just set fd 1 as CLOEXEC, so of course it will be closed upon the 'execve' call. Make sure you understand that. If you are able to edit 'test1' - you can just remove the 'fcntl' call.

But, on the other hand - if you can't edit 'test'1 at all - there might be a few ways to get around it.

1. If you are OK with 'stdout' and 'stderr' are pointing to the same place (maybe they are initially?) - you can just duplicate fd=2 into 1, using the following call: `dup2(2,1)`.
2. (Linux specific) if 'fork' is somehow called before the 'execve', you might be able to access the closed fd using the `procfs` filesystem. Assuming the parent process of 'test2' have the 'stdout' you want open in fd=1, you can just get its PID using `getppid()`, and then open `/proc/<ppid>/fd/1` (and of course - `dup2` the resulting fd into `1`).

Otherwise - there might be no way to "reopen" the file descriptor - as it was closed. Obviously, you can always `open` the file you want the `stdout` to point on from now on (`dup2` it to `1`!), and avoid the 'Bad file descriptor' error.

Good luck!